# How do you animate a cursor with CSS?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have looked at various stack overflow posts and a helpful website such as https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/animated-cursor/, but I really do not know why this animation is not working properly

Originally, I was trying to use a gif as a cursor, but with further research I found that gifs are not a supported cursor types. So, I converted each of the frames of the my gif into pngs and attempted to ue the @keyframes to make an animated cursor.

```css
body{
    background-color: red;
}

.cursor{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    animation: animate 0.01s infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame18.png'), auto;
    }   
    5%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame1.png'), auto;
    }
    10%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame2.png'), auto;
    }
    15%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame3.png'), auto;
    }   
    20%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame4.png'), auto;
    }
    25%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame5.png'), auto;
    }
    30%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame6.png'), auto;
    }
    45%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame7.png'), auto;
    }
    50%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame8.png'), auto;
    }
    55%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame9.png'), auto;
    }   
    60%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame10.png'), auto;
    }
    65%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame11.png'), auto;
    }
    70%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame12.png'), auto;
    }   
    80%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame13.png'), auto;
    }
    85%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame14.png'), auto;
    }
    90%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame15.png'), auto;
    }   
    95%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame16.png'), auto;
    }
    100%{
        cursor: url('images/cursor/frame17.png'), auto;
    }   
}
```

The @keyframes animate is invoked with the cursor class for testing purposes. I have made sure that the cursor class is clearly outlined so I can place my cursor in it, but NOTHING APPEARS! I don't know what the error is that is keeping this animation from playing out.

Comment: btw I have checked all image sizes, file locations, elements in the html file, and that the stylesheet is indeed linked to the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just realized how stupid I am... when I referenced an image in the stylesheet, the console started spitting out errors that it couldn't even find the image. Then I realized that the images I was referencing were in a different folder than the stylesheet. So my solution: just move the freakn images into the styling folder. Done.